# Ignore Resharper files in Team Foundation Server source control

Tags: version-control, tfs, resharper

How can I use Resharper without adding the Resharper generated files to the TFS server. Is there some sort of .ignore file/setting I can let the TFS maintainer modify. Or is it done client-side? We're using TFS 2008, but will be upgrading to TFS 2010 in the near future.

Comment: Are you talking about the `.resharper` files (which you *do* want in version control), or the _ReSharper.SolutionName *directories* (which you don't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using TFS 2008 and I have found that it doesn't add the resharper files by default, so unless you are explicitly selecting them in `Source Control Explorer` when doing a checkin you shouldn't have any worries.

The resharper folder will start with and underscore (ex. `_Resharper YourProject`) and I believe TFS knows to ignore those folders.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my TFS wanted to add all the _Resharper files, so I just right clicked on the _Resharper folder in Source Control Explore and selected "Undo Pending Changes":

[image]